# Date Filter with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a column of my table but for some reason I receive a 'out of range' error massage.

What I am doing:

```
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FailureLogStart").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:="*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

How my table looks like in columns:
A websiteID, B failureLogID, C FailureLogStart D FailureLogEnd

With the code above I would like to filter column C

Comment: Column Names are not listed in ListObjects collection, try to use `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("yourtablename").ListColumns("FailureLogStart")...` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing you want to filter your table on its 3rd column with the value of your `TextBox5`:

```
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("nameofthetable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=TextBox5.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: btw is there some way to update the code be behave Like  a SQL LIKE or a contains ?

Comment: maybe you're after something like `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("nameofthetable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox5.Value & "*"`